# Error when Deleting a group of hours from firebase server

Tags: reactjs, firebase, object, redux

I have a group of store hours that are created dynamically. I also have an edit button and a delete button. Each of these hours are stored in a hours property of the user object stored in firebase. I have tried to create an action that passes the delete() property that then updates the local store and the firebase backend.

The code below gives me an error of

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

This is the function used to grab the hours property and delete it

```
export function deleteStoreHours(hours) {
  let currentState = store.getState();
  let id = currentState.currentStore.id;
  console.log(hours);
  firestoreDb
    .collection("users")
    .doc(currentState.uid)
    .collection("hours")
    .doc(id)
    .delete()
    .then(
      store.dispatch({
        type: DELETE_HOURS,
        hours: hours
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

This is the button at the end of the mapped object that calls the delete function

```
  <span onClick={() => deleteStoreHours(data)} 
   className="hoursDeleteButton fas fa-trash"></span>
```

And finally here is the reducer call, I know this is wrong so any guidance would be appreciated

```
 case DELETE_HOURS:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentStore: action.hours
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.then(() => {
    store.dispatch({
            type: DELETE_HOURS,
            hours: hours
          })
})
```